# How to remove leading file path information from fish shell tab-complete suggestions?

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, autocomplete, fish

Using fish, typing `ls <tab>` in an example directory, the terminal displays:

```
$ ls
bar/  dir/  foo/
```

Continuing with `d<tab><tab>` this becomes:

```
$ ls dir/
dir/moredir/  dir/otherdir/  dir/subdir/
```

But I would much prefer to get what I am used to from bash:

```
$ ls dir/
moredir/  otherdir/  subdir/
```

Is there a fish configuration option that gets rid of the leading path information?

Comment: You may want to try out zsh shell. The same features as fish with extensions and configurabiltiy as a bonus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't like providing a negative answer, unfortunately this just isn't going to happen in Fish.

See [this Github request](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/7883).  According to an answer by one of the Fish maintainers on a (now-deleted) Stack Overflow question, that particular issue is just the most recent of many that have been closed as "will not implement".

Comment: @Flimm Thanks - I'll update.